# Is there any way to access <option> text when parsing forms using lxml.html?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying parse a html form that looks like that:

```
<select name="country">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">Andorra</option>
....
</select>
```

After I parse the document using lxml.html.parse, I can access the list of values using:

```
doc.forms[0].elements["country"].value_options
```

However, this returns a list of raw values (['1', '2', '3', '4' ...]) without the corresponding country names. Is there an easy way to get the contents of the option tag including both text and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use xpath to get go through html... try:

```
options = doc.xpath("//select[@name='country']/option")
option_text = [option.text for option in options]
```

Comment: You can use the `text()` function in your xpath to extract the text of an element. `option_text = doc.xpath("//select[@name='country']/option/text()")`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I could navigate the SelectElement via etree api.
I did it like this:
`options = {option.text:option.get("value") for option in select_element.iter("option")}`